# to write 10,000 x 5,000 term document matrix using 'Write Excel' operator

Tags: matrix, rapidminer

I am using rapid miner studio 6.0.007 with 8 GB ram trial license on windows 7 sp1. I have Core i7 with 8 GB RAM and 256GB SSD 840  PRO. I want to write term document matrix 5,000 columns and 10,000 rows. But I am unable to write because when using write excel operator memory utilization becomes maximum i.e. 98% of my 8 GB ram and after many hours I got the error message related with less available memory. Is there some optimal setting required in Rapid miner?

Answer (score 0):

The trial license is limited to a small amount of memory; 1Gb I believe. You can write the output as a CSV file which might require less memory.

Alternatively, you can use the last 5.n community version which is not memory limited.

Comment: Thanks dear. I used professional trial license and it provides 8GB RAM. Starter license has limited access up to 1GB.

Comment: Right so the trial will end and you will go down to 1Gb at that point. Did you try CSV export or the 5.3 version?

Comment: 5.3! OK I'll check it.

Comment: If that doesn't work there are techniques to process in batches but let's see how you get on with 5.3 first.